# Por qué no se calcula en el orden que quiero y no se ve reflejado en la vista

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hook

Tengo un inconveniente al momento de mostrar los resultados de un monitoreo de calidad.

1. Me calcula el totalEnc que lo tengo ubicado dentro del objeto calidadh.enc (Hook) en ese no hay problema me actualiza en la vista. El problema que tengo es que no me actualiza el resultadoFinal que lo tengo ubicado en calidadh.final.

```
const calcularTotal = async (value, porcentaje, method, idDivModificar) => {

        try {
            setcalidadh((prevState) => ({
                ...prevState,
                ["enc"]: (method == false && value == 1) ? calidadh.enc + porcentaje : (method == false && value == 0) ? calidadh.enc - porcentaje : calidadh.enc
            }));
            setcalidadh((prevState) => ({
                ...prevState,
                ["ec"]: (method == true && value == 1) ? 100 : (method == true && value == 0) ? 0 : calidadh.ec
            }));
            setcalidadh((prevState) => ({
                ...prevState,
                ["final"]: (ec == 0) ? 0 : calidadh.enc
            }));
        } catch (e) {
            alert("error " + e);
        }
    }
```

el divModificar es para cambiar el color. y el method es una variable boolean que me dice si es un ítem de alto impacto o no.
He intantado también ponerle el await antes de llamar el metodo:

```
    await setcalidadh((prevState) => ({
                ...prevState,
                ["enc"]: (method == false && value == 1) ? calidadh.enc + porcentaje : (method == false && value == 0) ? calidadh.enc - porcentaje : calidadh.enc
            }));
```

Porque necesito que primero se calcule `calidadh.enc`, después `calidadh.ec` y por último `calidadh.final`.
Funciona, pero no actualiza `calidadh.enc` y `calidadh.final` al mismo tiempo, en la vista no se ve reflejado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si notan me actualizó `calidadh.enc` pero `calidadh.final` no, cuando lo tengo programado `(calidadh.ec == 0) ? 0 : calidadh.enc` Debería dar el mismo resultado de `calidadh.enc`

el metodo que llaman todos los select es este:

```
     const onInputChange = e => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setcalidadh((prevState) => ({
            ...prevState,
            [name]: value
        }));
    }
```

Los select, llaman a las 2 funciones a la vez:

```
                   <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label>Tipificación</label>
                        <div className="input-group">
                            <div className="input-group-prepend ">
                                <div id="divcatorce" className="input-group-text">3%</div>
                            </div>
                            <select className="form-select form-control " name="catorce" id="catorce" value={catorce} onChange={(e) => { calcularTotal(e.target.value, 3, false, 'divcatorce'); onInputChange(e) }} required>
                                <option value="1">CUMPLE</option>
                                <option value="0">NO CUMPLE</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Espero haber sido claro. Saludos.

---

```
    const calcularTotal = async (value, porcentaje, method, idDivModificar) => {
        document.getElementById(idDivModificar).style.backgroundColor = (value == 1) ? "#e9ecef" : "#dc3545"; //colorea gris si cumple o rojo si no lo es
        document.getElementById(idDivModificar).style.color = (value == 1) ? "#000" : "#fff"; //El texto es negro si cumple o si no blanco
        document.getElementById(idDivModificar).innerHTML = (value == 1) ? porcentaje + "%" : "-" + porcentaje + "%";

        try {
            setcalidadh((prevState) => ({
                ...prevState,
                ["enc"]: (method == false && value == 1) ? calidadh.enc + porcentaje : (method == false && value == 0) ? calidadh.enc - porcentaje : calidadh.enc
            }));
            setcalidadh((prevState) => ({
                ...prevState,
                ["ec"]: (method == true && value == 1) ? 100 : (method == true && value == 0) ? 0 : calidadh.ec
            }));
            setcalidadh((prevState) => ({
                ...prevState,
                ["final"]: (calidadh.ec == 0) ? 0 : calidadh.enc
            }));
        } catch (e) {
            alert("error " + e);
        }
    }
```

select que llama la funcion:

```
                   <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label>Tipificación</label>
                        <div className="input-group">
                            <div className="input-group-prepend ">
                                <div id="divcatorce" className="input-group-text">3%</div>
                            </div>
                            <select className="form-select form-control " name="catorce" id="catorce" value={calidadh.catorce} onChange={(e) => { calcularTotal(e.target.value, 3, false, 'divcatorce'); onInputChange(e) }} required>
                                <option value="1">CUMPLE</option>
                                <option value="0">NO CUMPLE</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: ¿Por qué compartes una parte del código como texto y otra como imagen?

Comment: Pon todo como texto por favor, como imagen es dificil de ver.

Comment: También probé cada campo como una constantes individual: const [enc, setenc] = useState(100); y me da el mismo error... No se actualiza inmediatamente, si no despues que realizo otro cambio, es decir, me guarda el calculo para mostrarmelo despues.

Comment: Será posible que los cálculos asíncronos se estén terminando *después* de que actualizas tu pantalla?

Comment: La pantalla no se actualiza. Si le quito el async produce el mismo resultado

Comment: ¿Por qué no simplemente haces un hook para saber cuando se ha ejecutado cada `setcalidadh`?

Comment: Y como propones que lo haga. He intentado varias formas, oriéntame por favor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el viernes pasado realizando una validación con la habilitación de un boton de exportar a excel; claro mirando que se mostrara cuando haya por lo menos 1 resultado en la consulta. Me pude dar cuenta que el resultado del await solo funciona dentro de la función existente. Miren ustedes:

```
const submitBuscarFecha = async () => {
  Swal.fire({
      title: 'Cargando!',
      html: 'Espere mientras se cargan los datos...',
      timerProgressBar: false,
      didOpen: () => { Swal.showLoading() }
  })
  var res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/data/searchByDate/${table}/${nameFecha}/${fechaIni}/${fechaFin}`)
  const data = await res.data;
  document.getElementById('btnExportarExcel').style.display = data.length == 0 ? 'none' : 'block';
  setRecord(data);
  Swal.close();
}
```

Partiendo de eso:

1. tuve que independizar cada uno de los campos del formulario, según leí, es mejor para procesos mas complejos.
2. tuve que realizar 2 funciones async apartes para obtener los 2 primeros resultados, el resultado final se ajustaba de acuerdo a los anteriores calculos.

Todo quedó de la siguiente manera:

```
const [enc, setenc] = useState(100);
const [ec, setec] = useState(100);
const [final, setfinal] = useState(100);

const calcularTotal = async (value, porcentaje, method, idDivModificar) => {
  document.getElementById(idDivModificar).style.backgroundColor = (value == 1) ? "#e9ecef" : "#dc3545"; //colorea gris si cumple o rojo si no lo es
  document.getElementById(idDivModificar).style.color = (value == 1) ? "#000" : "#fff"; //El texto es negro si cumple o si no blanco
  document.getElementById(idDivModificar).innerHTML = (value == 1) ? porcentaje + "%" : "-" + porcentaje + "%";

  try {
    var renc = await calEnc(value, porcentaje, method)
    var rec = await calEc(value, method)
    setfinal(await (rec == 0 ? 0 : renc));
  } catch (e) {
    alert("error " + e);
  }
}

async function calEnc(value, porcentaje, method) {
  var r = (method == false && value == 1) ? enc + porcentaje : (method == false && value == 0) ? enc - porcentaje : enc;
  setenc(r);
  return r;
}

async function calEc(value, method) {
  var r = (method == true && value == 1) ? 100 : (method == true && value == 0) ? 0 : ec;
  setec(r);
  return r;
}
```

Espero que sea de utilidad al momento de realizar funciones async await complejas...